# How to manually add classmap in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using laravel 4.2

I have 2 application folders namely 'app' and 'backend':

[image]

I edited bootstrap/start.php so that when i access www.site1.com/backend it will go to 'backend' application. Hence, it will go to the 'app'.

```
// override app folder to backend
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') && ENVIRONMENT == 'backend')
{
    $path_settings['app']       = __DIR__.'/../backend';
    $path_settings['storage']   = __DIR__.'/../backend/storage';
}
```

I want to add a specific classmaps when I access /backend. I don't want to edit composer.json and add classmap there. How can I programattically do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Composer's ClassLoader](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) directly. Something like this:

```
$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();

// PSR-0
$loader->add('My\Backend', __DIR__.'/../backend');
// PSR-4
$loader->addPsr4(....);
// class map
$loader->addClassMap(...);

// activate the autoloader
$loader->register();
```

Comment: Ok. Wait i'll try this in the global.php file

Answer (score 0):

In your file `config/view.php` add :

```
'paths' => [
        realpath(base_path('backend'))
],
```